# PostGIS query to get a list of points

Tags: python, postgis

I have a PostGIS road network layer (all features are linestrings) which I am accessing in Python and would like to get the geometry for each feature as a list of points.  Something like [(lat1,lon1),(lat2,lon2),(lat3,lon3)...] would be ideal.  I am currently accessing the geometry by using the ST_AsText(geom) function, and then parsing the resulting string into points.  But this seems clunky, and since this seems like a pretty common/basic operation I would expect there to be a standard way to do it, but I am not seeing anything in the documentation.  Is there a function or good way to do it out there that I am just missing?

Comment: Use something like Fiona or Shapely and get an array or points directly?

Comment: ST_PointN will work, as will ST_StartPoint/ST_EndPoint if there are only two vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use psycopg2 and shapely to read PostGIS geometries into Python, like this:

```
import psycopg2
from shapely import wkb
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('SELECT geom FROM line_table WHERE gid=%s', (23,))  # one geometry
geom = wkb.loads(curs.fetchone()[0], hex=True)
geom.coords[:]  # [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]
```

If you have MultiLineString geometries instead, then each geometry has a `.coords` property, e.g. the first part is `geom.geoms[0].coords[:]`.

Note that the coordinates are Cartesian (x y) which is the norm in GIS software, not (lat lon) the human readable norm. If you need the later, there are a few tricks that can be used on either the server or client side.

Comment: This solution has worked really well but just want to add that anyone accessing polygon coordinates will want to change

  geom.coords[:]

to 

geom.exterior.coords[:] or geom.interior.coords[:] depending on whether you want the outer or inner ring of a polygon